# Openstreetmap tile loading problem with leaflet

Tags: javascript, html

i have a data sheet that I have to export to PDF.
So I have a view that contains an image, text and an area with an openstreetmap map.
There is also the body  that opens the browser’s print function.

The view is displayed correctly when I call it. By telling in the browser’s print preview the map is not fully loaded.
In the firefox console i have this error: NS_BINDING_ABORTED

How to force the full loading of tiles?

I use Laravel 8.83 and PHP 7.4

My view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>TEST</title>
<style>
    body {
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #000;
        max-width: 720px;

    }
    * {
        font-family: 'muli', sans-serif;
        font-style: normal;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .article-pdf {
        padding: 10px;
        max-width: 720px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .row {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        align-items: flex-start;
        margin: 0 -15px;
    }
    .col-6 {
        width: 50%;
        padding: 0 15px;
    }
    .image-container {
        position: relative;
    }
    .image-container::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        border: 0.5px solid grey;
    }
    .image {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        padding: 7px;
    }
    .card {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
    }
    .card .map-container {
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .card::after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
    }
    .topic {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-style: normal;
        line-height: 30px;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
    }
    .title {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 38px;
    }
    .subtitle em {
        font-weight: normal;
    }
</style>

<link href="{{ asset('css/site/leaflet.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="lang-fr" onload="window.print()">
<article class="article-pdf">
    <p class="topic">---[ TEST PDF ]---</p>
    <h1 class="title">Archive title</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <img class="image img-portrain}" src="{{ asset('storage/images/medium/' . $archive->resource) }}" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="map-container" id="map"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

<script src="{{ asset('js/site/leaflet.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/site/article.js') }}" defer></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS file :

```
const search_map = L.map('map').setView([28.787, 4.043], 5)
const tiles = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {minZoom: 4, maxZoom: 19}).addTo(search_map)
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad english...

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: Please share your code here